# This question is about image and inverse image

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

let $ f:X \to Y$ is a function and $ A \subseteq X$ and $B \subseteq Y$, which one is  correct?

$1.$ $f(A \cap f^{-1}(B))=f(A)\cap B$

$2.$ $f(A \cup f^{-1}(B))=f(A)\cup B$

$3.$ $f^{-1}(f(A) \cap B)=A\cap f^{-1}(B)$

$4.$ $f^{-1}(f(A) \cup B)=A\cup f^{-1}(B)$

With counterexample or membership, in "Set Theory with Applications" by Lin & Lin prove $1$. but what about $2,3,4$? Why are they wrong?

Comment: Hi! What makes you suspect this isn't true?

Comment: Follow an element $a \in A$ then follow an element $b \in B$. What happens in each case?

Comment: This is a four-choice question, in "Set Theory with Applications" by Lin & Lin prove 1. so 2,3,4 is not correct.

Comment: Just because you are asked to prove one case, doesn't mean the other cases are false.  I may have made a brain-farty error but I'm pretty sure 2) is true and fairly easy to prove.

Comment: Ah... I did make a brain-fart.  Suppose $f(a)= f(c)=w$ where $a\in A; c\not \in A; w\not \in B$.  Then $c\in f(A)\cup B$ but $c\not \in A\cup f^{-1}(B)$ (although $a$ is).

Comment: Have a look at this "compendium" of relationships between various images and preimages [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_set_identities_and_relations#Functions_and_sets).

Comment: As @fleablood pointed out second time round 2) is false. 3) and 4) don't make sense in general as the LHS is a subset of $X$ while the RHS is a subset of $Y$. Mathman: are you sure you have quoted 3) and 4) correctly?

Comment: @ Rob Arthan, You are right, I edit question.

Comment: Probably been asked and answered on this website multiple times. Suggest you search for an earlier appearance.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Do you have a specific link for this question?

Comment: If I did, I would vote to close the question as a duplicate. I'm suggesting that you search for a link. https://approach0.xyz/ might be helpful.

Comment: @fleablood: $f(c) \in f(A) \cup B$ is correct, not $c \in f(A) \cup B$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=Y=\{a,b,c\}$ be sets and $f:X\to Y$ be a function defined by
$$f(a)=a \ ; \ f(b)=f(c)=b.$$
In order to show that $2$ and $4$ are false, suppose that $A=\{a,b\}$ and $B=\{a,c\}$. Then
\begin{align}
f\left(A\cup f^{-1}(B)\right)&=\{a,b\};\\
f(A)\cup B&=\{a,b,c\};\\
f^{-1}\left(f(A)\cup B\right)&=\{a,b,c\};\\
A\cup f^{-1}(B)&=\{a,b\}.
\end{align}
Therefore, $f\left(A\cup f^{-1}(B)\right)\neq f(A)\cup B$ and $f^{-1}\left(f(A)\cup B\right)\neq A\cup f^{-1}(B)$.

In order to show that $3$ is false, suppose that $A=\{c\}$ and $B=\{c,b\}$. Then
\begin{align}
f^{-1}\left(f(A)\cap B\right)&=\{b,c\};\\
A\cap f^{-1}(B)&=\{c\}.
\end{align}
Therefore, $f^{-1}\left(f(A)\cap B\right)\neq A\cap f^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: OK. Thanks, now If we go ahead with membership, where will we get into trouble? I guess if  $ f(x) \in f(A)$ then $x\notin A$ in general

Comment: You are correct. If $f(x)\in f(A)$, then we cannot necessarily conclude that $x\in A$. It is worth to point out that if $f$ is one-to-one, then $3$ and $4$ are true, because $f^{-1}\left(f(A)\right)=A$. Moreover,  if $f$ is onto, then $2$ is true, because $f\left(f^{-1}(B)\right)=B$.